# String to regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I save in my database an String with a regex to validate one field, so when I bring from my back the regex to validate he comes with String type, so how can I convert that regex in a string to a regex to use with .test

So how I transform this:

```
"/^([a-z0-9]{5,})$/".test('12345');
```

Into this:

```
/^([a-z0-9]{5,})$/.test('12345');
```

tks

Comment: `new Regex(..)`?

Comment: `new RegExp` but yeah (and don't forget to slice the string to remove the leading and tailing slashes)

Answer (score 0):

```
var regExprString = "/^([a-z0-9]{5,})$/";
var regExpr = new RegExp(regExprString.substr(1, regExprString.length-2));
regExpr.test('12345');
```

Comment: This works tho but it would be helpful if you specify what you're doing

Answer (score 0):

The [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor takes a string which it will parse into a regular expression.

```
const pattern = "^([a-z0-9]{5,})$";
const regex = new RegExp(pattern);
regex.test("...")
```

/regex/ is basically just syntactic sugar for new RegExp("regex")